# File.Exists acts differently when access is denied to the file vs denied to the dir

Tags: c#, file-io, impersonation, file-exists

Based on the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of `File.Exists`, the `File.Exists` method should return `false` on any error, including the caller not having access to read the file.

I would expect it to return `false` both when the file is set to `FullControl` denied to the user and `FullControl` denied to the user to the directory the file lives in.

What I'm seeing is when the user has access to the directory, but not the file, `File.Exists` returns `true`; however, if the user has no access to the directory, `File.Exists` returns `false`.

I wrote a small program that demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string DirName = "TestDir";
        private const string FileName = "File.txt";
        private const string Password = "Password1";
        private const string UserName = "PermissionTestUser";
        private static WindowsImpersonationContext Identity = null;
        private static IntPtr LogonToken = IntPtr.Zero;

        public enum LogonProvider
        {
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2,
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
        };

        public enum LogonType
        {
            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
            LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4,
            LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5,
            LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8, // Win2K or higher
            LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9 // Win2K or higher
        };

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(DirName, FileName);
            try
            {
                CreateUser();
                CreateDir();
                CreateFile(filePath);

                // grant user full control to the dir
                SetAccess(DirName, AccessControlType.Allow);
                // deny user full control to the file
                SetAccess(filePath, AccessControlType.Deny);

                // impersonate user
                Impersonate();
                Console.WriteLine("File.Exists (with dir permissions): {0}", File.Exists(filePath));
                UndoImpersonate();

                // deny access to dir
                SetAccess(DirName, AccessControlType.Deny);

                // impersonate user
                Impersonate();
                Console.WriteLine("File.Exists (without dir permissions): {0}", File.Exists(filePath));
                UndoImpersonate();
            }
            finally
            {
                UndoImpersonate();
                DeleteDir();
                DeleteUser();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        private static void CreateDir()
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(DirName);
        }

        private static void CreateFile(string path)
        {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
        }

        private static void CreateUser()
        {
            DirectoryEntry ad = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
            DirectoryEntry newUser = ad.Children.Add(UserName, "user");
            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { Password });
            newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Test user" });
            newUser.CommitChanges();
        }

        private static void DeleteDir()
        {
            Directory.Delete(DirName, true);
        }

        private static void DeleteUser()
        {
            DirectoryEntry ad = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
            DirectoryEntries users = ad.Children;
            DirectoryEntry user = users.Find(UserName, "user");

            if (user != null)
            {
                users.Remove(user);
            }
        }

        private static void Impersonate()
        {
            if (LogonUser(UserName, ".", Password, (int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, (int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref LogonToken))
            {
                Identity = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(LogonToken);
                return;
            }
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);

        private static void SetAccess(string path, AccessControlType type)
        {
            FileSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(path);
            FileSystemAccessRule far = new FileSystemAccessRule(UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, type);
            fs.AddAccessRule(far);
            File.SetAccessControl(path, fs);
        }

        private static void UndoImpersonate()
        {
            if (Identity != null)
            {
                Identity.Undo();
                Identity = null;
            }

            if (LogonToken != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                CloseHandle(LogonToken);
                LogonToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of running this program is:

```
File.Exists (with dir permissions): True
File.Exists (without dir permissions): False
```

Can anyone explain why they differ?  In both instances, the user doesn't have read access to the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the default behavior of the `File.Exist`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):

> `File.Exist`
>
> Return Value Type: `System.Boolean`
>
> **true** if the caller has
>   the **required permissions** and path contains the name of an existing
>   file; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if path is
>   null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not
>   have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception
>   is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of
>   path.

And additionally

> The `Exists` method should not be used for path validation, this method
>   merely checks if the file specified in **path exists**. Passing an invalid
>   path to Exists returns **false**.

In other words, the **required permission** here, is the required permission to know **the existence of the file** (as the method name implies, `File.Exist`). And this means that as long as a user has access to the directory, it can know if the file **exists** or not.

Whether the user has file access or not doesn't affect the user's knowledge of the existence of the file, given the directory permission. But without directory permission, a user cannot know the existence of the file, and thus `File.Exist` returns `false`

---

**Edit (after feedback from comments):**

And probably the rather confusing part would be the last sentence:

> If the caller does not
>   have **sufficient permissions** to read the specified file, no exception
>   is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of
>   path.

The **sufficient permissions** to read the specified file is depending on the read-access of the **parent** directory rather than read-access of the specified file. (Additional comment by Mr. [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563532/rob)). The word "sufficient" may give some hint about the behavior that it will **only** depend on read-access to the *parent* directory is needed, *not* the read-access to the specified file.

But I admit that the explanation and the choice of word may sound rather *counter-intuitive* as people may intuitively interpret "sufficient permissions to read the specified file" as the read-access to the specified file rather than to the parent directory.

Comment: Your response would make perfect sense if it wasn't for the last sentence in the MSDN explanation, "If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path."  Since I explicitly removed Read access, I would expect it to return false...

Comment: @Middas you are right "sufficient permissions to read the specified file" this can mean have access to the directory or have access to the file. But if it means having access to the directory, I would also think that this is rather ambiguous to be written this way. Note the word "sufficient".

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, the "sufficient" word is very counter-intuitive.  I wish they would update the article to be more clear.

Comment: @Middas Being about to see a file is dependent on the read-access of the parent directory, *not* the read-access of the file.

Comment: @Middas no problem. Glad that it can be of any help. Good question and experiment by the way. That gives me better understanding too. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file does exist but `File.Exists(filePath)` returns false, that means the application has the read permission to **neither directory nor file**, which can be proved.

if you really want to test if a file exists or not, you can invoke `File.GetAccessControl(filePath)`. If the call returns without exception, it means the file does exist.

Comment: It should be noted that ```File.GetAccessControl(filePath)``` is only available in .NET Framework