# Checking the file in the application path -> always return false

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core

In my application during Debugging I want to check if the file was created in the application directory.

This file exists under path. The if (! File.Exists (pathFile)) method always returns false.

How to fix it?

EDIT:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/580708522589683722/640902364903112734/unknown.png

Comment: check the content of `pathFile` does it have the entire path? like `C:\foo\innerFoo\File.txt` ? On the second glance at it : Why the negation with `! `? Your  checking basically: IF does not exist, but the file exists, so the return value is false. Looks like everything is working as it should

Comment: This is path:
"D:\Xamarin Projects\XamarinDev\DzisUzbieramNa\DzisUzbieramNa\DzisUzbieramNa\Language\Languages.xlsx"

"D:\Xamarin Projects\XamarinDev\DzisUzbieramNa\" - Is project solution path.

If I open this path in the windows explorer, the file opens.

Comment: "method always returns false" or do you want to say, that it even returns false when you remove the file from the directory?

Comment: If the file exists under this patch, returns false.
If not, it also returns false.

Comment: I edited the post. I added a link to the photo with proof that the file exists.

Comment: ah it returns `true` even though the file exists

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640912174973321216/640912190487920660/unknown.png
When file not exists.

Comment: did you check the returning value by pulling it out of the if and catch the resulting value in an extra `bool ret = File.Exists (pathFile)` variable

Comment: Yes, this is value of bool _checkedValue.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640912174973321216/640914253439696916/unknown.png

Comment: wow, that's interesting, did you try to read out the directory and print the names of the files? looking for weird hidden characters in the filename?

Comment: is this the entire path that I see in the windows file explorer? or is it may be shortened down by windows? did you copy paste it from the address bar?

Comment: Path is correct. Next photo: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640912174973321216/640918497404387330/unknown.png

Comment: Problem is "Access denied": https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640912174973321216/640921357277855754/unknown.png

Comment: seems like we are getting closer. have you tried to run your .exe as admin? or even running visual studio as admin?

Comment: seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890188/5174469) would be a fitting duplicate